# SQL Server 2008 Management Studio Toolbox item is missing

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssms

In SQL Server Management Studio, the VIEW menu's TOOLBOX item is not visible.

Can any one help me make it visible?

Answer (score 0):

This is either because you are using the express version, or because there is no longer this item in SMSS.

Comment: If using express version then how to get those toolbox item in and use?